# How to update each records Date() value in a collection based on each records value in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
db.[collection].updateMany(
  {[identifying key]: [identifying value]},
  [{$set: {"[date key to update]": {$dateFromString:{ dateString:{$concat:[{$dateToString: { date: "$[date key to update]", format: "%Y-%m-%d"}},"T23:00:00.000+00:00"]}}}}}]
  )
```

in this example, I am setting the time stamp for each record that matches to be its date with the specific time of "T23:00:00.000+00:00"

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$dateFromParts` and supplement `23` to the `hour`.

```js
db.collection.update({
  <identifying key>: <identifying value>
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      <date key to update>: {
        "$dateFromParts": {
          "year": {
            $year: "$date"
          },
          "month": {
            $month: "$date"
          },
          "day": {
            "$dayOfMonth": "$date"
          },
          "hour": 23,
          "minute": 0,
          "second": 0,
          "timezone": "+0000"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dsUh2kCX_gO) for your reference.